# jenkins + gradle ，stuck at app:processReleaseAGCPlugin

Tags: android, gradle, push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

building an app get stuck at app:processReleaseAGCPlugin,here is some info:

Gradle Version - 6.7.1
Android Gradle Plugin - 4.2.2
Build tools - 30.0.2
Compile and Target SDK - 30

Answer (score 0):

Pls check whether an error occurs and provide details for us to trace this issue.

In addition, you are advised to use Android Studio to open or compile this project.
For more info, kindly refer to [this link](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-push-clientdemo-android#readme).